# Is it a cleaner way to write the following code in rust?

Tags: rust

```rust
for x in strategies {
  let mut flag = true;
  for y in x {
    if y {
      flag = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if flag {
    // do something          
  }
}
```

I really hate the use of the flag, and it adds unnecessary branch instructions. I am thinking if there is a way that we can execute `// do something` if the inner loop exit normally and don't do it if it breaks.

Comment: The code is too abstract. There's no general answer: it all depends on context. "Is a cleaner way" will therefore only give opinionated answers IMHO. Vote close.

Comment: @JHBonarius: whilst there may be even cleaner ways of achieving the overall aim of the provided code, even this snippet itself can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In place of the inner loop, you can take the negation of [`Iterator::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) applied over an identity method such as `|y| y` or [`std::convert::identity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/fn.identity.html):

```rust
for x in strategies {
    // if it's not the case that any are true
    if !x.into_iter().any(|y| y) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Equivalently, you can take [`Iterator::all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) applied over a negating method such as `|y| !y` or [`<bool as std::ops::Not>::not`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.not-1):

```rust
use std::ops::Not;

for x in strategies {
    // if it is the case that all are false
    if x.into_iter().all(Not::not) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Either way, if `x` is already an `Iterator`, then the call to `.into_iter()` is superfluous and can be omitted.

Comment: I think you got the logic reversed. Flag is set to false for any y true. And if it's false, the "something" isn't executed. And that's one of my issues with the OP, it's so abstract with bad naming, that it's easy to make a mistake. Maybe the whole construct can be replaced by something else altogether. We don't know, as we don't get enough details.

Comment: @JHBonarius: quite right, I've inverted the logic.  Of course, the variable naming and intent could be clearer and there could well be a better construct that more clearly aligns with the purpose of the code, but I do believe this answer addresses the question as asked.

Comment: Thank you. I think this solves my problem.